# When are you born a Hindu?

Tags: birth, children, parents

Well so my question is, when are you born a Hindu? So must a parent be Hindu or both? (Like in Judaism where the mother must be jew in order the child to be too) does this exist in Hinduism? If no, how do we know that we're Hindus?

Answer (score 2):

> *So must a parent be Hindu or both?*

If you go by [Manusmṛti](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manusmriti), it's the father that determines whether the child is Hindu or not.

> (question).—If a child is somehow born to a Brāhmaṇa from a non-Aryan woman, and another is born to a non-Aryan from a Brāhmaṇa woman,—with which of these would the ‘superiority’ lie?—([10.66](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/manusmriti-with-the-commentary-of-medhatithi/d/doc201801.html))
>
> The decision is that—‘**one born to an Ārya from a Non-Ārya woman may be an Ārya in quality**; **but one born to a Non-ārya even from an Ārya woman is always Non-Ārya**’—([10.67](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/manusmriti-with-the-commentary-of-medhatithi/d/doc201802.html))